# Django: Date range query performance problem

Tags: mysql, django-orm, date-range

On MySQL backend, Django converts `filter(date__year=2011)` to `... WHERE date BETWEEN 2011-01-01 00:00:00 and 2011-12-31 23:59:59.99` in SQL, which takes 3 seconds to execute. If I manually remove the time part and run it as `... WHERE date BETWEEN 2011-01-01 and 2011-12-31`, the execution time drops by 1/100 to 30 msec.

It seems that there is a fundamental problem with how the date range queries are interpreted. Any ideas to get around this?

If I cannot find a way using the Django ORM, I will add an extra year field to the model to store the year and do the query on that integer year field.

Thank you for your time.

p.s: For restrictions beyond my control, the environment is Django 1.1. This may be fixed or better optimized in newer versions of Django.

Comment: Have you already indexed datetime field?

Comment: yes. otherwise the manually modified version would take long too, i think. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried [**`range`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)? looks like the django's generated sql is equal to your raw sql. Works with 1.1

`.filter(date__range(datetime.date(2011,1,1), datetime.date(2011,12,31))`

equivalent to:

`SELECT ... WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' and '2011-12-31';`

Comment: thanks. the range is better. the problem was that i was giving the start and end values as datetime.datetime objects instead of datetime.date. my bad.